# Main Less Code Change for IE 11 or Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, less, internet-explorer-11

I use the main less compiler in order to create my css file. For my badges, I use e.g. this code for Google Chrome:

```
.badge-default{
  position: relative;
  left: 18px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Now I would like also to use my side in IE11, but as I know -webkit-background-clip and -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; are not compatible with IE11. How can I change my less code in order to use the specific class .badge-default which is actually supported in the browser?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble in other browsers, I'd recommend this article: http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html

CSS tricks has a fallback method using modernizr: https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: I was on the modernizr page, but I cannot find the backgroundclip download? Do you have any idea?